# Get enum and send enum value

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I use spring, spring restcontroller, I have an enum in Java.

```
public enum PaymentModeEnum {
    CASH, DEBIT, CHECK, CREDITCARD;
}
```

How to get enum value in javascript and to to send enum value to java?

Comment: pass it as string like `CASH`, and in rest controller `method(@RequestParam PaymentModeEnum enum){}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set/get enum value using Javascript REST call to Spring API-

- Enum name can be set using path variable or query string. Below example is for query string.
  `//https://localhost:8444/getByEnumVal?enumVal1=CASH
  @RequestMapping(value = "/getByEnumVal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String setEnum(
          @RequestParam(value="enumVal1", required=false) String enumVal1) {
      Service.methodcall(enumVal1);
      ...
  }`
- Enum value can be returned as JSON directly, or by setting it in POJO
  `@RequestMapping(value = "/getEnumVal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getEnumVal() {
      return PaymentModeEnum.CASH;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you have a frontend with some javascript that calls a REST endpoint written in Java, using Spring.
I don't know how to share an enum between javascript and Java (they are different languages), but you can either send its ordinal value, or the name of the enum value. I would go with the latter.

This way you can just get it as a query parameter in your endpoint. Like so:

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = some/path
    method = GET)
public SomeTypeAsResponse method(@RequestParam(name = "payment_mode") PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.For extracting Enum in JavaScript do something like below:

```
var enumvar = document.inputId.Packages.com.MyClass$MyEnumYesNo.YES
```

2.For sending Enum from Javscript to RestController, pass it as a String directly and then map it as a Enum in the methods input parameter in Controller.